# sass css navbar variables for visited links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, navbar

I'm trying to style my navbar with some sass css variables that I came across on github.

```
$navbar-default-link-color:                $dlu-blue !default;
$navbar-default-link-hover-color:          $dlu-dark-gray !default;
$navbar-default-link-hover-bg:             $dlu-light-gray !default;
$navbar-default-link-active-color:         $white !default;
$navbar-default-link-active-bg:            $dlu-dark-gray !default;
```

I want my navbar link backgrounds to turn light gray on hover and dark gray when visited and active.  Right now, my links that are dropdown menus will turn dark gray, but my normal links do not change color when visited.  I understand that's probably because visited is not a variable that I have listed above.  Is there a $navbar-default-link-visited-bg variable out there?  I did not see one on github or anywhere else.

When clicked on a dropdown, the background color changes correctly:
[image]

When I clicked on the home link, background color remains unchanged:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: The point of `variables` is that you can make your own and use them for styles in CSS. EG: `$navbar-default-link-visited-bg: #ffffff;` and then `a:visited { background-color: $navbar-default-link-visited-bg; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit difficult to answer without further clarification. From what I can gather, you either want to:

1. add styles to distinguish between links the user has clicked/viewed previously, as opposed to those they have not.
2. add styles to distinguish the currently active page link in your menubar.

---

#### 1. Styling Previously Visited Links

To style links which a user has previously seen, use [the `:visited` link pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited). You can combine this with Sass variables you already have to achieve a consistent color scheme, which might look something like:

```css
a:visited {
  /*=targets ALL previously visited links */
  background: $dlu-light-gray;
  }
```

#### 2. Styling the Active Menubar Item

> ***Edit**: whoops, just noticed the **twitter-bootstrap** tag on your original question! In this case (assuming you've included [any/all necessary Javascript for the navbar component](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) in your page) Bootstrap should handle `.current` class toggling, as I'd assumed.*

To style the currently active page link in the menubar, you'll need to add a class to the item via Javascript. From the description of your dropdowns, it sounds like you're using a framework which handles class toggling internally in some manner. So let's assume a `.current` class is applied to the active menubar item, your Sass might read as follows:

```css
.menubarItem.current {
  background: $dlu-light-gray;
  }
```

---

## Takeaways

Just pasting [variables in to your Sass](http://sass-lang.com/guide) will not actually apply any styles to your markup. If you want to further customize your CSS beyond whatever defaults you're using, you'll need to actually implement those variables!

Lacking further details, I've made up the above classnames, variables, etc. for the sake of example. But I'd imagine this is enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another technique for you *Dave*, may seem a little tedious, but I like it...

- On your home page, for instance; add a class to signify the page is homepage,  to it's
  wrapper class. *ie*, for home: `<div class="page-wrapper home"></div>`
- *Do this to all your all pages.*
- Now within your SASS you can easily organize and define the active
  link's styles per link via nesting.

*ie.*

```
.home { 
    .home-button { 
         background: $active; // so basically if homepage, home link active
     }
}
```